# How to change the orientation of axis to a direction given by tuple in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

For example the orientation of histogram in the picture below is (2,-2)
[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MattDMo I give an image showing the behavior I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [transformations](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html). Since you did not provide any code that would plot the non-rotated picture, I'm using a simple example:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

n = numpy.random.normal(size=10000)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.set_xlim(-4, 4)
ax.set_ylim(-4, 4)

base_trans = ax.transData
tr = matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(-30) + base_trans

ax.hist(n, normed=True, transform=tr, bins=20)

fig.savefig('t.png')
```

[image]

Notes:

- I do not know what you mean by a "direction given by a tuple". In your picture the axes are clearly not just rotated, but moved as well (the (0,0) point is not on the x-axis). I only used rotation in this example; see [docs for Affine2D](http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D) for more transformation properties.
- In order for your graph to not look skewed, you must match the plot's aspect ratio, x/y limits, and the transformation's scaling coefficients. In the example I used the aspect 1 and the same scale for x and y axes, so I could just use the `rotate_deg()` method without any additional corrections.

Comment: Tuple, I mean a vector specifying orientation, using angle is also fine.